# type-punning a char array struct member

Tags: c, strict-aliasing, type-punning

Consider the following code:

```
typedef struct { char byte; } byte_t;
typedef struct { char bytes[10]; } blob_t;

int f(void) {
  blob_t a = {0};
  *(byte_t *)a.bytes = (byte_t){10};
  return a.bytes[0];
}
```

Does this give aliasing problems in the return statement? You do have that `a.bytes` dereferences a type that does not alias the assignment in `patch`, but on the other hand, the `[0]` part dereferences a type that does alias.

I can construct a slightly larger example where `gcc -O1 -fstrict-aliasing` does make the function return 0, and I'd like to know if this is a gcc bug, and if not, what I can do to avoid this problem (in my real-life example, the assignment happens in a separate function so that both functions look really innocent in isolation).

Here is a longer more complete example for testing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct { char byte; } byte_t;
typedef struct { char bytes[10]; } blob_t;

static char *find(char *buf) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) { if (buf[0] == 0) { return buf; }}
    return 0;
}

void patch(char *b) { 
    *(byte_t *) b = (byte_t) {10}; 
}

int main(void) {
    blob_t a = {0};
    char *b = find(a.bytes);
    if (b) {
        patch(b);
    }
    printf("%d\n", a.bytes[0]);
}
```

Building with `gcc -O1 -fstrict-aliasing` produces `0`

Comment: What is `byte_t`? Did you mean `uint8_t`?

Comment: for the record, my gcc 10.2.0 run as `gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -fstrict-aliasing` still prints 10 with no warnings

Comment: @MightyPork markup problem, fixed now

Comment: haha well that changes it quite a bit. Try to post a complete example with includes and the exact gcc invocation, I still can't reproduce the problem. clang and tcc also agree that the result is 10

Comment: @MightyPork Full example that provokes gcc:
```
typedef struct { char byte; } byte_t;
typedef struct { char bytes[10]; } blob_t;

static char *find(char *buf)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            if (buf[0] == 0) {
                    return buf;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}

void patch(char *b) {
        *(byte_t *)b = (byte_t){10};
}

int main(void) {
        blob_t a = {0};
        char *b = find(a.bytes);
        if (b) {
                patch(b);
        }
        return a.bytes[0];
}

Comment: still no problem, i just changed it to print the result - https://share.ondrovo.com/2021-03-05/main.c - are you using some ancient GCC version?

Comment: Tried a couple of gcc versions, happpens with gcc versions 6.4.0 and 10.1.1, but not 5.5.0. I use `gcc -Wall -O1 -fstrict-aliasing foo.c`

Comment: right, -Os and -O1 cause the problem. I suggest you edit the question with the full example and this important detail..

Comment: For the record, still happens if I disable all -O1 optimizations except `inline-functions-called-once`, `unit-at-a-time`, and `tree-fre`.

Comment: There cannot be any aliasing violation in the return statement, as accessing a named object by its name necessarily uses its defined type. There is an aliasing violation in `*(byte_t *)a.bytes`.

Comment: I'm looking at the disassembly and gcc completely removes the call to `patch` in the longer example with O1. However, if I add a `printf()` in the `patch` function, it is included and the result is 10.

Comment: @EricPostpischil why is dereferencing of a.bytes an aliasing violation? does this mean that the `patch` function in the longer example is bad C?

Comment: @ErikCarstensen: `a.bytes` is a pointer to `char` (due to automatic conversion of the array). Accessing that `char` as a `char_t` accesses it as a type it is not and that is not any of the allowed types listed in the aliasing rule. Therefore it violates the aliasing rule.

Comment: I don't know enough about strict aliasing to write an answer, but here is another workaround: If I add `__attribute__((noinline))` to the patch function, GCC won't inline it, won't try to be clever about aliasing rules and reoder the writes incorrectly, and the problem goes away. In real code though, I'd suggest just rewriting it to avoid punning

Comment: @EricPostpischil right! so I can access a bytes_t using a char[], but not access a char[] as a bytes_t. Meaning that patch() in the longer example is broken when viewed in isolation, memcpy is required. Thanks!

Comment: @ErikCarstensen: If clang or gcc ever recognize that an operation stores a bit pattern which has been written previously using a different type, they will sometimes behave as though the operation writes the storage with that earlier type.  Jumping through hurdles to get around the way clang and gcc process `-fstrict-aliasing` is a fool's errand, since `-fno-strict-aliasing` will Just Plain Work with or without such workarounds, and `-fstrict-aliasing` may malfunction even with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that those two structs are not compatible types. And so there can be various problems with alignment and padding.

That issue aside, the standard 6.5/7 only allows for this (the "strict aliasing rule"):

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object,
>   ...
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members

Looking at `*(byte_t *)a.bytes`, then `a.bytes` has the *effective type* `char[10]`. Each individual member of that array has in turn the effective type `char`. You de-reference that with `byte_t`, which is not a compatible struct type nor does it have a `char[10]` among its members. It does have `char` though.

The standard is not exactly clear how to treat an object which effective type is an array. If you read the above part strictly, then your code does indeed violate strict aliasing, because you access a `char[10]` through a struct which doesn't have a `char[10]` member. I'd also be a bit concerned about the compiler padding either struct to meet alignment.

Generally, I'd simply advise against doing fishy things like this. If you need type punning, then use a union. And if you wish to use raw binary data, then use `uint8_t` instead of the potentially signed & non-portable `char`.

Comment: I agree the standard is not very clear. It could be argued that the effective type of the object being modified is the element type `char` since `a.bytes` is converted to a pointer to the first element. In contrast, for `*(byte_t *)&a.bytes`, the effective type of the object being modified is clearly `char[10]`.

Comment: If `pointerValue` is an expression of type `T*`, the expression `*(pointerValue)` refers to an object of type `T`.  While it would have made sense for the Standard to have defined `[]` as an operator that can act directly upon an array type without pointer decay, and the authors of clang and gcc seem to believe that it does so, I see nothing in the text of the Standard that would justify such an interpretation.

Comment: @supercat While the [] operator indeed only works on pointers, the definition of effective type states that it's the same as the declared type. So pointer decay in the expression doing the lvalue access shouldn't matter, only the type which was used for declaration.

Comment: @Lundin: Different parts of the Standard use the term "object" in slightly different and inconsistent ways, and there is no way to interpret the Standard in a manner which would treat as defined everything that "obviously" should be without treating as defined constructs which clang and gcc make no effort to process meaningfully.  If one believes the Committee didn't think anyone should care about whether the constraints would actually allow construct like `someStruct.array[i]`, or whether compilers should be expected process code meaningfully when doing otherwise would be obtuse, ...

Comment: ...then it becomes possible to interpret the Standard in a consistent fashion which would be compatible with most existing code (including a lot of code that fails under `-fstrict-aliasing`) but still allow most useful optimizations.  Further, one could nix the "character-type" exceptions and allow more optimizations while breaking very little non-contrived code.  Unfortunately, the back ends of clang and gcc are willfully blind to things at least some of the authors of the Standard probably thought were sufficiently obvious that they could go without saying.

Comment: @Lundin: Can you cite anything in the Standard that would specify that the type of a decayed pointer is anything other than a pointer to the element type, and that the type of a dereferencing expression wouldn't be the element type?  That would make `someStruct.array[i]` violate constraints for non-character-type arrays, but unless one is worried about implementations treating that as an excuse to ignore common sense, such a constraint violation shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @supercat The part I referred to is the C17 6.5/7 definition of effective type: "The _effective type_ of an object for an access to its stored value is the declared type of the object, if any." Then 6.3.2.1 regarding lvalues "When an object is said to have a particular type, the type is specified by the lvalue used to designate the object. A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type...". So it is all very vague what to do with a situation where you have an array and then lvalue access that one through a struct containing the array element type as first member (or as array).

Comment: do you mean that it should work if I change the type to "typedef struct { char bytes[10]; byte_t x; } blob_t;"? That still fails with gcc -O1 -fstrict-aliasing.

Comment: @ErikCarstensen No, it would need to be a `union` with those same members. Then it's well-defined under something called "common initial sequence".

Comment: Are there other problems with 'char' than portability and signedness? In my real-world code, I use unsigned char, and protect this with static assertions that sizeof(char)==1. This because I want to enjoy the aliasing privileges of a character type.

Comment: @Lundin: Nothing in the Standard implies that an access via an lvalue of the form `structLValue.array[index]` is an access via anything other than the element type.  The address of the structure object is used to form the pointer value `structLValue.array`, but once the pointer is formed neither the structure nor its type is involved anymore.

Comment: @Lundin: According to the text of C99, in-scope visibility of complete union type declaration containing two structure types is supposed to be sufficient to allow the use of either type to inspect Common Initial Sequence members of either type, but the authors of clang and gcc pretend that it requires that accesses be performed using an lvalue which is formed from a union-type lvalue using only `.` or `[]` operators.  I see nothing in the Standard that would support such an interpretation, but clang and gcc insist upon it.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in `*(byte_t *)a.bytes = (byte_t){10};`. The C spec has a special rule about character types (6.5§7), but that rule only applies when using character type to access any other type, not when using any type to access a character.

Comment: You may lvalue access an object through a struct that includes the effective type of the object among its members though.

Comment: @Lundin (NEVER MIND - I'LL GO AND READ YOUR ANSWER FIRST!) I wonder if that is only true when actually using that member to access the object? The wording in the standard is a bit vague, but it seems a reasonable limitation to impose. (And the wording is not just for struct types, but also array and union types.)

Comment: @IanAbbott My point with that comment is that as far as pointer aliasing is concerned, it would be fine to access the array (character or not) through a struct lvalue access, if the struct used for the access included an identical char array among its members. Alignment would be still be a concern.

Comment: @Lundin Your answer makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: @Lundin: If accessing in a character array through an identical character array contained within a different struct type is allowed, what do you make of https://godbolt.org/z/8Gvov5 ?

Answer (score -1):

According to the Standard, the syntax `array[index]` is shorthand for `*((array)+(index))`.  Thus, `p->array[index]` is equivalent to `*((p->array) + (index))`, which uses the address of `p` to compute the address of `p->array`, and then without regard for `p`'s type, adds `index` (scaled by the size of the array-element type), and then dereferences the resulting pointer to yield an lvalue of the array-element type.  Nothing in the wording of the Standard would imply that an access via the resulting lvalue is an access to an lvalue of the underlying structure type.  Thus, if the struct member is an array of character type, the constraints of N1570 6.5p7 would allow an lvalue of that form to access storage of any type.

The maintainers of some compilers such as gcc, however, appear to view the laxity of the Standard there as a defect.  This can be demonstrated via the code:

```
struct s1 { char x[10]; };
struct s2 { char x[10]; };
union s1s2 { struct s1 v1; struct s2 v2; } u;

int read_s1_x(struct s1 *p, int i)
{
    return p->x[i];
}
void set_s2_x(struct s2 *p, int i, int value)
{
    p->x[i] = value;
}
__attribute__((noinline))
int test(void *p, int i)
{
    if (read_s1_x(p, 0))
        set_s2_x(p, i, 2);
    return read_s1_x(p, 0);
}
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    u.v2.x[0] = 1;
    int result = test(&u, 0);
    printf("Result = %d / %d", result, u.v2.x[0]);
}
```

The code abides the constraints in N1570 6.5p7 because it all accesses to any portion of `u` are performed using lvalues of character type.  Nonetheless, the code generated by gcc will not allow for the possibility that the storage accessed by `(*(struct s1))->x[0]` might also be accessed by `(*(struct s2))->x[i]` despite the fact that both accesses use lvalues of character type.